# Regex match javascript/php function name in str

Tags: javascript, jquery, regex

I'm trying to highlight code (and eventually sanitize the HTML) but my regex is not matching just the function name and params. I am no good at regex, it kinda boggles me to begin with. Also when I try to use `.replace()` on my matched result to sanitize the HTML and add the `<pre>` brackets, it gives me the error `Uncaught TypeError: undefined is not a function` which I am guessing is because it's not returning a basic string?

```
var content = $('#content'),
    html = content.html(),
    result = html.replace(/\s.*\(.*\)\s/gi, "<pre>$&</pre>");

    // When trying to add the <pre> tags in the last line of code
    // And use this to sanitize my html.match() I get a error

    // escapedRes = result.replace(/&/g, "&amp;")
    //           .replace(/</g, "&lt;")
    //           .replace(/>/g, "&gt;")
    //           .replace(/"/g, "&quot;")
    //           .replace(/'/g, "&#039;");

    // Uncaught TypeError: undefined is not a function 

content.html(result);
```

**[JSFiddle Example](http://jsfiddle.net/WASasquatch/3Q7By/)**

## Broken Sanitize Fiddle

```
var content = $('#content'),
    html = content.html(),
    result = html.match(/\w+\(.+?\)/g);
var escapedRes = result.replace(/&/g, "&amp;")
    .replace(/</g, "&lt;")
    .replace(/>/g, "&gt;")
    .replace(/"/g, "&quot;")
    .replace(/'/g, "&#039;")
    .replace(/(/g, "&#40;")
    .replace(/)/g, "&#41;")
    .replace(/\*/g, "&#42;")
    .replace(/$/g, "&#36;");
var result = escapedRes.replace(result, '<pre>'+escapedRes+'</pre>');
content.html(result);
```

**[JSFiddle Example](http://jsfiddle.net/WASasquatch/ULWeF/)**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use this regex:

```
/\w+\(.+?\)/g
```

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/3Q7By/5/)

### Update:

On your sanitizing part, you need to do

```
 result = html.match(/\w+\(.+?\)/g)[0];
```

as match() returns an array.

Also, you'll need to escape `(` and `)` and `$` with backslash, as they have special meaning in regex.

Comment: Thanks, that's part of the problem.

Comment: @WASasquatch, what is the other part?

Comment: It's in my question. I updated code to show problematic code. Which is based on using a `match()` in result insidead of replace

Comment: Please re-read my comment and question. This is based on the `html.match(/\w+\(.+?\)/g)` code as the `<pre>` is added afterwards.

Comment: @WASasquatch, .maatch() will only give you the matched part  which is `function(){ ... }`. Why are you using that?

Comment: Sanitizing it... basically i'm going to match more then just function names, this is just part of the code. Which I'll be sanitizing `= ( ) ; [ ]` etc trying to start simple before going crazy with the regex. I'm wondering why it errors out. is the result from `match()` not a normal string?

Comment: Something like this, if that is valid Regex, but still same error in question http://jsfiddle.net/WASasquatch/ULWeF/

Comment: The problem is that, there are no special characters in the `result` and hence it is `undefined`.

Comment: `()` are. See the updated fiddle. Are you saying the function can't fail if there isn't a match?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/51046/discussion-between-amit-joki-and-wasasquatch)